# Appending <s:select> to a table row using jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2

How can we add a struts  tag to a table using jquery append.I have defined a list in my action and am using this as the list for  tag.I have tried with

```
$("tableid").append(
"<tr><td><s:select name='test' id='test'  list='listfromAction'/></td></tr>");
```

but its not working can anyone tell me what am missing here;

Comment: Where is this javascript ? in jsp ? or separate javascript file ?

Comment: this javascript function is in the same jsp page

Comment: what is not working and what error if any your are getting

Comment: am not getting any error.But this struts select box is not appending to the table.If i remove the <s:select> append line from my javascript all the other fields are appending to the table.

Comment: As told in the answer, use "" properly.Additionally i suggest you to use some kind of tool for your UI and firebug is a good one which can show you any HTML/CSS/JS syntax error correctly

Comment: How is a struts tag useful in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The above code does not work because you are using `"` improperly.

If you use `append("` to begin, you cannot then again use `"` without escaping them, or instead, using `apostrophes`.

```
$("tableid").append("<tr><td><s:select name='test' id='test' list='listfrmoAction'/></td></tr>");
```

This will work properly. See the [jsFiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/fgUQ9/).

*(Note: I did not use self enclosing tags, just for the purpose of convenience. Although, they do work, you can remove and test and see.)*

Comment: Tried firebug complains unterminated literal, nothing happens in your fiddle too...

Comment: Don't use a self-enclosing tag.

Comment: @elvisandkumar this seems to be an issue that is related to your browser. It would seem Chrome and Firefox fully support adding Struts tags, while Internet Exlporer doesn't. [Here's Proof](http://imgur.com/B6pA3)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the question doesn't make sense to me.

jQuery (and all JavaScript) runs after the HTML has been generated. Creating a strugs tag would create something that is not going to be parsed by struts.

You need to generate the HTML that is output by struts, not a struts tag

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. The above answer does not work properly. The tag gets converted  into proper html tag, but the browser(chrome) gives parsing problem. However if you take the parsed html code and put it all in a single line. It works perfectly. So the problem , according to me is that, the parsed html code comes in mulitple lines.

To fix this.. what i am doing is that.. you create a sample row in the jsp using the struts tags, using jquery just append this row one more time. like this

`var tbody = document.getElementById("interfaceMessagesTable")
        .getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        tbody.append($("#onerow"));`

where my table is like this
`<table id="interfaceMessagesTable" width="100%">                       <tbody id="tableBody" valign="top"> <tr> <td> <s:select ..../> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>`